# when use Bootstrap not works

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I used Bootstrap for my template in wordpress for split header, but it does not work, I used below code in header

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <?php
            Better_Mag::generator()->get_main_slider();
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            hello world
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6">
hello world
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
<?php
              Better_Mag::generator()->get_main_slider();
?>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, works,just let me know what is different, and if i need slider be in right, its possible? cause slider now goes left and "hello world" goes right

Comment: Please Don't forget vote up. this answer your useful

Comment: it marked as useful, just pls let me know what is different? and if i want slider stay on right, its possible? cause slider with your code goes left

Comment: Your slider check image width than again try. something right .